# Loading HTML data vs loading unformatted data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

When loading data using AJAX, what is preferred: 
Loading html data e.g.

```
<div class="message">
    <span class="author">John Smith</span>
    <span class="date">01/01/17</span>
    <div class="message-content">
        Example text
    </div>
    <div class="message-actions">
        <a href="upvote">Upvote</a>
        <a href="downvote">Downvote</a>
        <a href="comment">Leave a comment</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

(The above is entirely fictional, by the way)

Or loading JSON data e.g.

```
{
"author":"John Smith",
"date":"01/01/17",
"text":"Example Text"
}
```

I realise that loading JSON data would place less load on the server, but I'm primarily concerned about loading speed for the user. So basically, my question is, how does loading html data-for example using JQuery's `.load()` method, compare to loading JSON data and rendering it as html using Javascript, in terms of total time before a user can see the displayed result?

**EDIT** after @vol7ron's comment:
This is a messaging application, and so these messages will be displayed one after the other in a scrolling area of the screen. The number of messages is variable.

Comment: How much data? usually a combination of the two is the best performance.  HTML causes the browser to generate DOM elements, which is slow.  If you're going to be doing any formatting/editing, it's better to do that before you've bound the data to the DOM.  However, on initial load, it's good to have either placeholder HTML, or a first sample for the user to see.  Basically: more information needed

Comment: @vol7ron Edited

Comment: 10? 1000? 10000? The number doesn't matter too much.  There's a scale of insignificant to significant.  Checkout lazy-loading.

Comment: @vol7ron Up to about 1000, at absolute maximum.